# Cannot get php page to display center

Tags: css, html, forms

I cannot get my form to display center, I've tried numerous ways with the CSS but cannot figure out what is preventing it from centering on page.  I've just the same style with all the other pages but for some reason this one refuses to behave ;). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Women Who Can - Subscription page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/style.css">
        <!--Fonts-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../steph/_css/ss-pika.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../_css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Subscribe For Free</h1>
            <div>
                <b class="text-white" style="float:right">Already a member? <a href="../login/index.html" class="text-white" style="text-decoration:underline;">Sign in</b></a>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="unique-section" class="row">
                <div class="section">
                    <form method="post" action="subscribe.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="forename" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="womenwhocan.com" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Description:</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Please tell us something interesting about yourself" style="height:200px; width:300px;font-size:12pt; align-vertical:" name="profile_description" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="*******" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="*******" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            By signing up, you agree to our Terms of Use, Privacy Policy, and Anti-spam Policy
        <div>
        <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to display the "container" in the middle of the page. You can try to add this:

```
<div class="container" style"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

Or just add the following in your css file for the container class:

```
display: block; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but unfortunately that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css

```
    <style>
    .container{
      width: 500px!important;
      margin:0 auto;
    }

    .row{
      display: block!important;
    }

    </style>
```

Comment: Hey thanks Ameh.  This does center the page, however my form fields now span right across and so I lose the form control

Comment: How about you make .row flex again let's see what happens

Comment: Didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
body h1{
  text-align: center;
}
.section{
  width:100%;
  margin: 0, auto;
  text-align: cnter;
}
div#unique-section {
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Women Who Can - Subscription page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../_css/style.css">
        <!--Fonts-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../steph/_css/ss-pika.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="../_css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Subscribe For Free</h1>
            <div>
                <b class="text-white" style="float:right">Already a member? <a href="../login/index.html" class="text-white" style="text-decoration:underline;">Sign in</b></a>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="unique-section" class="row">
                <div class="section">
                    <form method="post" action="subscribe.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="forename" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="womenwhocan.com" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required/>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Description:</label>
                            <textarea placeholder="Please tell us something interesting about yourself" style="height:200px; width:300px;font-size:12pt; align-vertical:" name="profile_description" class="form-control" required></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="*******" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
                            <input type="password" name="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="*******" required/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            By signing up, you agree to our Terms of Use, Privacy Policy, and Anti-spam Policy
        <div>
        <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```